# Want COUNT to return a 0 or 1 in PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a few lines of code that's not giving me answer as I expect.

Please help me to write the best way for it:

```
if ("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM completed WHERE userid = $memid AND filetid = $fileid1 LIMIT 1"){
    if (1) goto enz;
}
```

I want **if** `count = 1 goto enz`, `else (count is 0)` and *continue with rest of program*

Comment: what problem do you get?

Comment: I seem to always goto enz, even when I know I shoud have gotten a 0 answer

Comment: In first if() it is a string, which means true, it goes to the 2nd if, it is (1), it goest to enz. I don't know php. but it seems this logic for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try in this way :

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT (*) as count FROM completed WHERE userid = $memid AND filetid = $fileid1 LIMIT 1";

if ($result = mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if($row['count'] == "1"){
          //Enter you code here to goto 'enz'
        } else {
          //Continue with rest of program
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this code:

```
function getConnected($host, $user, $pass, $db)
{

    $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
    mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, 'utf8');

    if ($mysqli->connect_error)
        die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') ' . mysqli_connect_error());

    return $mysqli;
}

$mysqli = getConnected($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);
$sql = "SELECT COUNT (*) as count FROM completed WHERE userid = $memid AND filetid = $fileid1 LIMIT 1";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
        if($obj->count == "1"){
          //Enter you code here to goto enz part 
        } else {
          //Continue with rest of program
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
$sql="SELECT COUNT (*) as cnt FROM completed WHERE userid = $memid AND filetid = $fileid1 LIMIT 1";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if ($row['cnt'] == 1) {
//Do your code (goto enz)
} else if ($row['cnt'] == 0) {
//Continue rest
}
```

Answer (score 2):

All other answers are **Correct**. But it is also a good practise to check for **Errors**.

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$sql = "SELECT COUNT (*) as count FROM completed WHERE userid = $memid AND filetid = $fileid1 LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql));

// Check for errors
if(!$result){
   printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if($row['count'] == "1"){
      // Success. Write your code for redirection
    }else{      
      //Continue with rest of program
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: @devpro: You are welcome :) In 2016, I hope everyone will use it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
$sql    = 'SELECT COUNT (*) as foo FROM completed WHERE userid = $memid AND filetid = $fileid1 LIMIT 1';
$result = mysql_query($sql, $link);

if($row['foo']>1) {
 goto enz;
}
```

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **mysqli** DB DRIVER then put following code

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT (*) as total FROM completed WHERE userid = $memid AND filetid = $fileid1 LIMIT 1";

if ($result = mysqli_query($con,$query)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if($row['total'] == "1"){
          //Make your code here
        } else {
          //Make rest of the code
        }
    }
}
```

And If you are using simple **mysql** DB DRIVER then

```
$query = 'SELECT COUNT (*) as total FROM completed WHERE userid = $memid AND filetid = $fileid1 LIMIT 1';
$result = mysql_query($query, $link);
$row    = mysql_fetch_array($result)

if($row['total'] == "1"){
    //Make your code here
} else {
    //Make rest of the code
}
```